# PyQt: Where can I find an explanation about stylesheet and its describing string?

Tags: pyqt, stylesheet

I mean stylesheet of the function setStyleSheet of QApplication

Answer (score 3):

The Qt docs would be a good place to start.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html

You can apply stylesheets to individual widgets, or to QApplication to apply a style to everything.